# FindControls from userControl inside an Accordion in the content aspx page

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, accordion

I have an aspx page (Default.aspx) with an Accordion control and a button (the page is based on a master page).
Inside one Pane of this Accordion I have an userControl, something like this:

```
<Content>

<ucDetails:Details ID="userControlDetails" runat="server" />

</Content>
```

Now I need to access of the Enabled property of the button in the aspx page inside my userControl.

Until now I've tried:

```
Button btnSend1 = (Button) this.NamingContainer.FindControl("btnSendRequest");
Button btnSend2 = (Button) Page.Parent.Parent.FindControl("btnSendRequest");
Button btnSend3 = (Button) Page.Parent.FindControl("btnSendRequest");
```

The first one return NULL
and the others return exception ("Object reference not set of an instance...").

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Luigi
:

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button btnSend1 = new Button();
    btnSend1 = (Button)userControlDetails.FindControl("btnSend1");
    bool enabled = btnSend1.Enabled;
```

Is this what you're going for?

Comment: I'm trying this:


Button btnSend1 = new Button(); 
btnSend1 = (Button)Parent.FindControl("btnSend1"); 
bool enabled = btnSend1.Enabled;

but it gives me null.

The userControl is inside an Accordion Pane in the Default.aspx page. 

Luigi